# why this cant save any data in my database?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, ckeditor5

hi guys im new anyone can help me
i cant save my input data in my database

i use ajax like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
   var name= $('#editor').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "{{ route('sendcom') }}",
            data:{ name: name },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
        } );
  });
});
```

and i try use ckeditor5 so i have sendcom route and this is my box and button:

```
 <form action="{{ url('sendcom') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="editor" name="editor"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
```

and i try to get my data in my controller like this

```
public function sendcom(Request $request){

        $content = $request->name;


        User::updateOrCreate([
            'contract' => $content
        ]);

        return response(['success' => 'contract save success.']);

    }
```

but its just refreshing my box and nothing hapend

Comment: First, prevent the default behavior of the submit button by passing `e` to the click callable `... $("#btn").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ....`. Second, make sure your route is available by running `php artisan route:list`, and if you can't find the route, run `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a CKEditor problem?

Comment: Your ckeditor uses `name=editor` bit your ajac uses `name=name`... And you are reading `name` on your controller...

Comment: In addition to @AmooAti's comment, add success and error callbacks into your $.ajax body, like -> `$.ajax({ ... success: function(data) {}, error: function(error) { console.log(error)}` and check if there's any error in your console. Also, check your laravel.log for any errors.